# Restream live stream using VLC and display using HTML5 video tag

Tags: html, video, vlc

I currently have a server and client connected through a tunnel using OpenVPN. My goal is to use the server to grab and restream the camera feed from the client on the server using a HTML5 video tag. The server has a public IP, so the idea is to allow people to view the client's video stream, through this server.

I'm using VLC, and using the graphical method, I'm able to view the video stream on VLC itself. The steps I used are as follows:

1. Media -> Stream -> Network Tab -> for network URL field, `http://10.8.0.6:8080/path/stream/`
2. Stream -> Next -> for the destination, change from File to HTTP -> check Display Locally -> Add
3. for the Path field, I put `/stream/live` -> unchecked Activate Transcoding (otherwise it doesn't work) [EDIT2: changed port to 8181]
4. Stream.

The video shows in VLC, but when I add the following lines to my index.html file on the server, it doesn't work:

```
<video id="id" width="640" height="480" src="http://203.xxx.yyy.zzz:8080/stream/live" autoplay="autoplay">
</video>
```

where 203.xxx.yyy.zzz is the public ip address of my server.

The video doesn't show; there's only a black screen. Can anyone help me?

EDIT: I don't mind if it's not a graphical solution; a command line solution is fine too.

EDIT2: I realised that both input and output streams were on the same port, so I changed the output to port 8181. On top of this, I'm also trying to use MJPEG as to mux instead, so that I can simply display it on a webpage using an `<img>` tag (This would be preferred over using `<video>`). I created a new profile called "Video - MJPEG". Under the "Encapsulation" tab, I chose MJPEG. Under the "Video codec" tab, I checked "Video", chose the M-JPEG codec from the drop-down list, left Bitrate at 800kb/s, upped the frame rate to 30 fps, and put 1 for the resolution scale. Despite using this profile, the stream didn't show when I used `<img src="my.ip.address:8181/stream/live />` in my index.html. Please help!

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @cocoseis the latest version of chrome at the time of writing that post